# How to get user queryset who commented to certain post in Python, Django?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I would like to get a user queryset who commented in certain post.
Assume that there is a post(id=3), and there 8 people commented on it.
I want to notify something to 8 people, so I want to get 8 people's queryset(user objects).
How can I do it?

I have model User, Post, and Comment.

For example,

```
User.objects.get(comment__Post.objects.filter(id='3'))
```

like this way. (of course, the upper doesn't work)

Help me!

---

User model is Django User model.

```
class Post(models.Model):
    post_id = models.CharField('username', max_length=150)
    ...

class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    com_id = models.CharField('username', max_length=150)
    ....
```

Comment: Can you show how you defined the models please?

Comment: does you Post model has has user information?

Comment: User model is Django User model.

Comment: @HSPark i mean how you defined the Post and Comment models

Comment: @alessioferri20 I added them!

Comment: the Post and the Comment models as no foreign key to the user model or viceversa?

Comment: @alessioferri20 yes, no foreign key for each

Comment: @HSPark then how you are able to do what you asked? there is no link between a User and a Post or between a User and a Comment

Comment: @alessioferri20 Ah, then it needs to change 'post_id'(user id who posted) to user foreign key....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally your models should look like the following

```
class Post(models.Model):
    posted_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...

class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    commented_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

And your requirement can be achieved through the following query

```
post = Post.objects.get(id=3)
user_ids = list(Comment.objects.filter(post=post).values_list('user__id', flat=True))
```

This will return the list of user ids

If you need queryset,

```
users = User.objects.filter(id__in=user_ids)
```

Comment: You don't want to cast `user_ids` to a `list` there, because that will evaulate the queryset, causing an unnecessary query to the database.  Simply drop the `list(` ... `)`, and the django ORM will be smart enough to do the whole query in one go.  You can even drop `flat=True` in this case, I think.

Comment: But that will be Comments model objects. not the user model objects

Comment: Not at all, because you're doing `User.objects.filter(id__in=Comment.objects.filter(post=post).values_list('user__id'))`.  What this translates down to, is a single SQL query with (I believe) a `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: I tried , `output = Comment.objects.filter(post=post).values_list('user__id')`, I got a queryset as output. according to you it should be user objects. Then I tried `output.filter(username='xxx')`. This is throwing an error ie, Cannot resolve keyword 'username' into field. Choices are: post, comment, commented_by

Comment: No, `Comment.objects.filter()...` will most certainly be `QuerySet<Comment>`.  I'm saying that if you do `.values_list('user__id')`, you can then use _that_ queryset as an argument to `User.objects.filter()`, and save a database query.  Please read my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48499551/how-to-get-user-queryset-who-commented-to-certain-post-in-python-django/48500054?noredirect=1#comment83995257_48500054) carefully, and see that I am filtering on `User` at the top level.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion you should add a `OneToOneField` to the model `Comment` and to the model `Post` that relate to the `User` model like this:

```
from django.conf import settings
...
class Post(models.Model):
    ...
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.User, related_name="posts")
    ...

class Comment(models.Model):
    ...
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.User, related_name"comments")
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name="post_comments")
    ...
```

The for your queryset you will be able to do:

```
User.objects.get(posts__id=3)
for comments in Comment.objects.get(post_comments__id=3):
    comments.user # this are the user that commented on a certain post.
```